# Why string comparision results always false

Tags: shell, centos, string, variable

I am trying to do a one time check about apache's mod-status page for updates
like this(this is just a test script):

```
firstcontent=$(lynx -dump http://some-server/server-status-page)
echo $firstcontent > /tmp/myfirstcontentfiles.txt
nextcontent=$(lynx -dump http://some-server/server-status-page)
prevcontent=`cat /tmp/myfirstcontentfiles.txt`
#this always returns false, but their contents are same
if [ "$prevcontent" == "$firstcontent" ]; then   echo "match"; fi
#but this returns true 
if [ "$nextcontent" == "$firstcontent" ]; then   echo "match"; fi
```

My question is why $prevcontent and $firstcontent comparision returns false whilst I am supposed to get a true return value?
is anything happening behind the scene when I am saving it in a file?

Comment: You'll lose distinctive whitespace characters when you do `echo $firstcontent > /tmp/myfirstcontentfiles.txt`. They'll get replaced by blanks. Try `echo "$firstcontent" > /tmp/myfirstcontentfiles.txt` instead.

Comment: Double quoting `$firstcontent` on the second line should fix your bug as @Mark says. I don't recommend storing the downloaded data in shell variables though. Instead, try downloading directly to a file and using the `cmp` command to compare. Also consider using `wget` or `curl` for better portability.

Comment: I would use <code>diff</code> for comparing the two files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766) to understand the why. The 1-sentence version is: always use double quotes around variable substitutions.

```
echo "$firstcontent" >/tmp/myfirstcontentfiles.txt
```

mostly works: it doesn't collapse whitespace or expand wildcards in the value of the variable. However this still removes trailing empty lines (command substitution does that) and, in some shells, the `echo` command expands backslashes. In your script, the easiest way to write the pristine output of the command to a file is to do it before it reaches the shell:

```
firstcontent=$(lynx -dump http://some-server/server-status-page | tee /tmp/myfirstcontentfiles.txt)
```

Comment: Thanks Gilles :) Had to create extra files for my comparisons before this. Now it is working with my variables.Thanks a ton :)